# Inserting a dynamic feature to an esixting app bundle

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, ondemand

I am reading the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/dynamic-delivery) up and down but I haven't been able to find a **definite** answer. Can I create and include a dynamic feature for my app bundle **after** the core apk compilation and upload it to Google Play **separately** or should they always be bundled together?

Any info  will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, they don't need to be compiled together and a dynamic feature module (DFM) could be added in an existing precompiled .aab file.

However, I don't know of a tool today that would be able to compile them separately and insert the DFM correctly in the AAB. You're free to try making one though, it shouldn't be too hard given that the AAB is just a zip file and the format is documented and opensource.

The only thing to make sure of really is that the package name and version code are the same for all modules.

Comment: I am looking for a way to deliver extra content to my app w/o re-uploading the whole thing every time. Like uploading **additional** dynamic features **separately** to Google Play. From your answer I take it that there is no support for this kind of thing, right?

Comment: That's correct, it's not supported at the moment. May I ask what is your use-case? Assets for a game? Or machine learning model? Assets, code or native libraries?

Comment: I am building a riddle game. I thought of having a binary engine and separate asset bundles for each riddle. Apparently a CDN is my only choice now.